How would the introduction of a change in phonology for first-language learners affect their L1?
Imagine that a new English word is coined, like “rng”, which doesn’t follow the normal phonotactics. It catches on for cultural reasons. People pronounce it phonetically as best they can, without converting it to “ring” or “erng”.
A generation of infants acquiring their L1 from their environment are going to be exposed to a phonotactic rule that is not part of the older generations’ L1, even though the older generation uses it. (Their brains do not have the phonemic segmentation or generative grammar that a native speaker would, like the difference between the Hindi retroflex ‘d’ and dental ‘d’.)
According to generative grammar, the L1 learners should not just be able to pronounce the word “rng” with fluency, but it should affect their generative grammar. For example, would it enable only ‘r’ to precede a consonant with no vowel in between? Or all consonants? Or only ‘r’ and ‘ng’ with no vowel? Or something else?
Is there any empirical evidence from which it is extrapolated what would happen?

Why would the infants be exposed to a phonotactic rule that’s not part of the older generation’s phonotactics? To the infants, there will be a word variantly pronounced /rɪŋ/ or /ərŋ/, neither of which obviously breaks any phonotactic constraints of English. Infants learning this word would not learn it as /rŋ/ because they learn it from hearing it, not from reading it; it would end up being similar to a word like buoy variantly pronounced /bɔɪ/ or /buːi/. (It’s true that /ŋ/ doesn’t generally only appears after lax vowels, but a sequence like /ərŋ/ doesn’t ‘feel’ unphonotactic.)

The usual reason this happens is because those learners' parents (or whatever influences in their life) are trying to imitate foreign words from a more prestigious language. This usually involves introducing new phonemes, rather than new phonotactics, though I don't see why it couldn't involve phonotactics as well (e.g. allowing a consonant to appear in the coda when it couldn't before).
When this happens, one option is that the learners incorporate it into their knowledge of the language, and eventually it becomes a standard part of the language. This is how Swahili got /ð/ (from Arabic) and English got /ʒ/ (from French).
The other option is that they don't. They never treat it as truly part of the language, and even if they affect it in foreign words, it doesn't get incorporated into the phonology in the long term. This is what happened to aspirated consonants and front rounded vowels in Latin (from Greek).

Is it really true that it's more likely for new phonemes to be borrowed than phonotactically disallowed sequences?

@Someone211 I'm honestly not sure. It might be a selection bias, where new phonemes are more obviously borrowed than new sequences.
